# Radiator fluid leaking from reservoir

Tags: civic, cooling-system, leak

I had the head gasket done because of overheating 2 years ago, now it seems the problem is back. When the car starts to overheat I will put in coolant but the next day if I do a long distance drive I will smell the coolant being burnt from the hip of the engine and I am thinking it is coming out of the reservoir. One time I stopped for gas and when I got out I saw a large amount of coolant under the car so I opened the hood and it looked like it came from the reservoir.

Comment: How do you notice the overheating? Does the temperature gauge go high or do you get a warning light? Or is it a steam / smell thing? When you saw the coolant that looked like it was coming from the reservoir, what did you notice.

Answer (score 1):

It could be something as simple as the rubber seal on the underside of the cap.  This would be the first thing I would check.

Failing that, have a compression or leakdown test done to establish the health of your engine.